# Is Recipe v1.13 as implemented in Brightway2 the same as Recipe 2016?

Tags: brightway

I found that Recipe v1.1 is Recipe 2016, so logically Recipe v1.13 should be too.
But when looking at the midpoints in the activity browser, I notice two things:

1. There is only a midpoint for human toxicity in general (like in recipe 2008) instead of a distinction between cancer and non-cancer
2. Mineral resource depletion (which is called metal depletion in the ab) is expressed in Fe-eq (recipe 2008) and not in Cu-eq (Recipe 2016).

This leads me to wonder: are only these two midpoints taken from Recipe 2008? Or are all midpoints actually from Recipe 2008? Or maybe for point 2 it is simply a naming mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Brightway uses the LCIA implementation provided by the ecoinvent centre. Their documentation only mentions ReCiPe 1.13 in the release of 3.7 (filename LCIA_implementation_3.7.pdf), where they state that these CFs were published in 2008, and were imported from Simapro 8.3.0.0.

I guess there are versions 1.X of both ReCiPe 2008 and 2016 :)